# Scrolling Textview in android

Tags: android, textview

In my application i have to implement an automatically scrolling textview, I referred [this](http://androidbears.stellarpc.net/?p=185) link    .

Now I have a scrolling tetxview.But according to my requirement is that I have a string array(I have parsed and I have some string)..Consider the array may be

```
 string[] array=new string{"fgsdfd","gdfghdjhsd","gdfjhsgfhds"};
```

Now i want this array to be displayed in  that textview(which will scroll automatically).

I want like this:

```
 fgsdfd   gdfghdjhsd    gdfjhsgfhds------------------>this will scroll automatically
```

This is my textview(scrolling):

```
 <TextView
    android:text="Really Long Scrolling Text Goes Here.... ..... ............ .... ...."
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:padding="5dip" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

How can I set an array of string to a tetxview..Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using StringBuilder.

```
String[] array = { "fgsdfd", "gdfghdjhsd", "gdfjhsgfhds" };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sb.append(array[i]);
}
txtView.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can merge all of your string in one string by [`StringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and apply it to the `TextView`.

I've implemented my own TextView with scrolling by wrapping textview (and maybe some other views)

```
private Runnable scrollRight = new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
                    // can control scrolling speed in on tick
        topScroll.smoothScrollBy(1, 0);
    }
};
```

and in new Thread I invoke:

```
while (!interruptScroll){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(50); // control ticking speed
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    topScroll.post(scrollRight);
}
```

and by manually scrolling the scrollView i interrupt the scrolling (such an automatic scrolling while not interrupted by user).

Comment: And BTW - to implement autoscroll use ScrollView, smoothScrollBy and threads\timers.

Comment: k...Thanks dilix...Can u do 1 more favour..In above code the scrolling is happening very slowly..i want them to scroll little bit fast..How can i accomplish in above code..

Comment: first part is only a variable and post second part in (new Thread("you code in Runnable")).start(); and your scrolling code will be run in other thread.

Answer (score 0):

try for this,

```
<TextView
android:text="Really Long Scrolling Text Goes Here.... ..... ............ .... ...."
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/TextView03"
android:padding="5dip" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```